# word frequency counter in r using n-gram

Tags: r, frequency, text-mining, cpu-word

I would like to perform a certain operation which will transform the data in the provided format.

### Input

```
colA                             colB
textA textB textC textD           m
textA textB                       n
textB textC                       p
textB textC textD                 q
```

### Output

```
type    col_a              col_b(frequency)           col_c
unigram textA                        2                  m+n
unigram textB                        4                m+n+p+q
unigram textC                        3                 m+p+q
unigram textD                        2                  m+q
bigram  textA textB                  2                  m+n
bigram  textB textC                  3                 m+p+q
bigram  textC textD                  2                  m+q
trigram textA textB textC            1                   m
trigram textB textC textD            2                   m+q
fourgram textA textB textC textD     1                   m
```

Need to do this separately for unigram,bigram,trigram and fourgram and then rbind the results.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea

```
n_grams <- function(n) {
  unigrams1 <- unique(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$colA, ' '), unique)))
  t <- apply(combn(unigrams1, n), 2, paste, collapse = ' ')
  t1 <- sapply(t, function(i) paste(df$colB[grepl(i, df$colA)], collapse = '+'))
  return(t1[sapply(t1, nchar)>0])
}
#testing the function

n_grams(1)
#    textA     textB     textC     textD 
#    "m+n" "m+n+p+q"   "m+p+q"     "m+q" 
n_grams(2)
#textA textB textB textC textC textD 
#      "m+n"     "m+p+q"       "m+q" 
n_grams(3)
#textA textB textC textB textC textD 
#              "m"             "m+q" 
n_grams(4)
#textA textB textC textD 
#                    "m"
```

To construct your desired output, then

```
df1 <- data.frame(rbind(stack(n_grams(1)), stack(n_grams(2)), stack(n_grams(3)), stack(n_grams(4))))
df1$freq <- nchar(gsub('\\+', '', df1$values))
df1 <- df1[,c('ind', 'freq', 'values')]
df1
#                       ind freq  values
#1                    textA    2     m+n
#2                    textB    4 m+n+p+q
#3                    textC    3   m+p+q
#4                    textD    2     m+q
#5              textA textB    2     m+n
#6              textB textC    3   m+p+q
#7              textC textD    2     m+q
#8        textA textB textC    1       m
#9        textB textC textD    2     m+q
#10 textA textB textC textD    1       m
```

Comment: by m,n,p,q i meant integer and i don't want their concatenation but sum instead.

Comment: and how are we supposed to know what you 'meant'? Why don't you include what you 'mean' in your question? The output is exactly the same as what you have posted in your question. If this is not what you want then  change your question.